# Proper typing on propOr

Tags: typescript, ramda.js

I have the following code

```
import { propOr } from 'ramda'

export const firstOrNull = propOr(null, 0)
```

But typescript warns me on the ***zero parameter***

> Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

[image]

What I need to do to solve this?

Comment: Did you try `propOr (null, '0')` with a string rather than a number?

Comment: No because I want the first element from the array

Comment: Understood, but `propOr` is designed to work on arbitrary objects.  Arrays in JS are implemented as Objects, with special handling of non-negative integer keys.  Thus `a['0']` and `a[0]` are really the same thing.  But the former may help with the TS issue. 
 Ideally the TypeScript typing should be updated to allow for integers, strings, or Symbols, but I suspect this would both work with Ramda and solve the TS issue.